# How to get return values from javascript to android as String?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In the following Javascript function which returns a `newpid` value. From android button click I will call javascript function with passing parameters.Now my question is I want to get newpid value from javascript function to android and store it as String.

```
    web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = (Integer) view.getTag();

                Log.d(TAG, "called" + str1.get(position)+position);

                web.loadUrl("javascript:process_save(\"" + str1.get(position) + "\")");

                    web.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface,"androidWebViewClient");


            }
        });
```

**My Javascript function:**

```
function process_save(action) {
    var newpid = 0;
    if (check_mandatory()) {
        var pid = geturlparameter("pid");
        var wfid = geturlparameter("wfid");
        var transid = geturlparameter("transid");
        var partialapprove = geturlparameter("partialapprove");
        var partialactivityid = geturlparameter("activityid");
        var loginid = geturlparameter("loginid");
        loginid = (loginid == null) ? 0 : loginid;
        if (pid == null && parseInt(wfid) > 0) {
            CallVbMethod("initiateprocess", "{'workflowid':'" + geturlparameter("wfid") + "','activityid':'" + activityid + "','activityname':'" + activityname + "','review':'" + action + "','skip':'','loginid':'" + loginid + "'}", function (result) {
                showerror(result[result.length - 1]);
                if (result[0] != "") {
                    newpid = result[0];
                    saverecords(newpid);
                    parent.disablePopup();
                }
            }, false, false);
        }
        else if (parseInt(pid) > 0 && parseInt(transid) > 0) {
            showerror("processid : " + pid);
            saverecords(pid);
            CallVbMethod("changewflowstatus", "{'transid':'" + transid + "','status':'1','sqlquery':'','review':'" + action + "','skip':'','activityid':'" + partialactivityid + "','processid':'" + pid + "','partialapprove':'" + partialapprove + "','loginid':'" + loginid + "'}", function (result) {
                showerror(result[result.length - 1]);
                if (result[0] != "") {
                    newpid = pid;
                    showsuccess(result[0]);
                    parent.disablePopup();
                }
            }, false, false);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Mandatory field not entered");
    }
    window.androidWebViewClient.tellAndroidPid(newpid);
    return newpid;
}
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- API Level **19+ (KITKAT and above)**

  ```
  webView.evaluateJavascript //JS value received on => ValueCallback<String>#onReceiveValue
  ```
- Old versions

  ```
  loadUrl("javascript:...") //JS value received on => JavaScriptInterface#callback
  ```

==>

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "javascriptinterface");

 private void saveProcess(int position) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:process_save('" + position + "');",new ValueCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
                // value is the result returned by the Javascript as JSON
                // Receive newpid here
                Log.d("JS",value);
            }
        });
    } else {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:javascriptinterface.callback(process_save('" + position + "');");
    }
}

private class JavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void callback(String value) {
      // Receive newpid here
    }
}
```

Checkout this [working test project](https://github.com/KhaledLela/JavascriptRetunValue), **Hope that guide you to achieve your target.**

Comment: Thank you so much .I will check it and let you know.

Comment: I/check pid:  get pid:null returning null   private class JavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void callback(String value) {
            // Receive newpid here
            Log.i("check pid"," get pid:"+value);
        }
    }  this callback method not in enable state.  javascriptinterface.callback(newpid);//this is what i calling from javascript function. if condition is executing but not returning any values except null.

Comment: Ensure that webView page complete loaded after `onPageFinished` is called try to fire `saveProcess()`

Comment: @SeyedAliFathima my loadUrl  was missing semicolon, Please check my update, BTW I created working test example to show you that is working with me.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you are saying.The method callback(String value) I have used in JavaScriptInterface is not in enable mode?I don't know where I  missed.

Comment: Its not semicolon but a close bracket ')' to close callback method.I noticed as well.Please tell me why still my callback method is in disable mode.The process_save is working good but the callback method is not firing .

Comment: Thank you I will check your test project.

Comment: `callback method` will not fired if you run on device with android version 19+ (KITKAT and above). and `onReceiveValue` will be called

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in your activity

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void tellAndroidPid(String pid){
    //you can save your pid in here,
    Log.i("check pid"," get pid:"+pid);
}
```

Add js interface for your webview

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(this,"androidWebViewClient");
```

Invoke native interface in js method

```
function process_save(action) {
    ...
    window.androidWebViewClient.tellAndroidPid(YOUR_PID);
    ...
}
```

Don't forget to enable js feature

```
setting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);//here setting is WebSettings,you can get it by webview.getSettings()
```

**Edit:**

You should add a js interface before invoking it

```
web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
web.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
web.addJavascriptInterface(JSInterface,"androidWebViewClient");
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = (Integer) view.getTag();

        Log.d(TAG, "called" + str1.get(position)+position);

        web.loadUrl("javascript:process_save(\"" + str1.get(position) + "\")");

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much .I will check it and let you know

Comment: javascript:process_save(\""+str.get(position)+"\")..I wanna send my function's parameters dynamically while button click.can you please tell me what code should I use while button click?

Comment: What is the use of my android button click? What should I call within button click?.There is no function call right?Using interface I can only able to get data from javascript function but the first thing is to call javascript function through button click by passing parameters dynamically and the second thing is to get the return value.Please explain me.

Comment: You can invoke js method as you did ,just invoke tellAndroidPid in your js method where you want to invoke,you don't have to return it.

Comment: invoke window.androidWebViewClient.tellAndroidPid(YOUR_PID) in your js method ,your native code will be invoked,and you can handle it in your native code.

Comment: Okay I will try it.

Comment: public class JavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
        public void tellAndroidPid(String pid){
            //you can save your pid in here,
            Log.i("check pid"," get pid:"+pid);
        }
    }  The function tellAndroidPid() is not in enable mode and is not calling

Comment: Did you enable javaScript in your webview?

Comment: Yes I have reedited my question please check it.I have enabled JavaScript also

Comment: I reedit my answer too,you should add js method before invoking it,please check my code.

Comment: Nope.Its not working.I did what you guide.Please listen me some.How the javascript function will return ? Only we send parameters to process_save() in js method,it can able to fetch pid from db and return that pid. if I call the js interface  before calling js function how it will return pid?.And the most important is the function tellAndroidPid() still in disable after i change the code as per your last update.

Comment: There is no way that js can return value for your native code,only callback to native method.